# What do Presbyterians believe about predestination?

Tags: predestination, presbyterianism

What do Presbyterians believe about predestination? I've googled various websites but have not found a clear answer.

Comment: The Grace Presbyterian church I went to here in NZ had a very Calvinist view of predestination, being reformed and holding to the Westminster Confession. Not sure if that's necessary for all Presbyterian churches though.

Comment: Which websites were you looking at that we're clear? The Presbyterian Church holds to the Westminster Confession and so has about the clearest teachings on predestination of any denomination!

Comment: Thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

The following, quoted from the [Free Presbyterian website](https://www.fpchurch.org.uk/about-us/important-documents/the-westminster-confession-of-faith/#cp10) where the [Westminster Confession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Confession_of_Faith) is referenced, is Chapter 10 of the Confession, being headed 'Effectual Calling' :-

(Each statement is referenced, by letter (a.b.c), to quotations from the Holy Bible.)

> 1. **All those whom God hath predestinated unto life, and those only**, He is pleased in His appointed and accepted time effectually to call,a) by His Word and Spirit,b) out of that state of sin and death, in which they are by nature, to grace and salvation by Jesus Christ;c) enlightening their minds spiritually and savingly to understand the things of God;d) taking away their heart of stone, and giving unto them a heart of flesh;e) renewing their wills, and by His almighty power determining them to that which is good,f) and effectually drawing them to Jesus Christ:g) yet so, as they come most freely, being made willing by His grace, (h).

> aRom 8:30; Rom 11:7; Eph 1:10-11. b2 Thess 2:13-14; 2 Cor 3:3,6. cRom 8:2; Eph 2:1-5; 2 Tim 1:9-10. dActs 26:18; 1 Cor 2:10, 12; Eph 1:17-18. eEzek 36:26. fEzek 11:19; Phil 2:13; Deut 30:6; Ezek 36:27. gEph 1:19; John 6:44-45. hSong 1:4; Ps 110:3; John 6:37; Rom 6:16-18.

> 2. This effectual call is of God’s free and special grace alone, not from anything at all foreseen in man,i) who is altogether passive therein, until being quickened and renewed by the Holy Spirit,k) he is thereby enabled to answer this call, and to embrace the grace offered and conveyed in it.l)

> i2 Tim 1:9; Tit 3:4-5; Eph 2:4-5,8-9; Rom 9:11. k1 Cor 2:14; Rom 8:7; Eph 2:5. lJohn 6:37; Ezek 36:27; John 5:25.

> 4. Others, not elected, although they may be called by the ministry of the Word,p) and may have some common operations of the Spirit,q) yet they never truly come unto Christ, and therefore cannot be saved:r) much less can men, not professing the Christian religion, be saved in any other way whatsoever, be they never so diligent to frame their lives according to the light of nature, and the law of that religion they do profess.s) And, to assert and maintain that they may, is very pernicious, and to be detested.t)

> pMatt 22:14. qMatt 7:22; Matt 13:20-21; Heb 6:4-5. rJohn 6:64-66; John 8:24. sActs 4:12; John 14:6; Eph 2:12; John 4:22; John 17:3. t2 John 9-11; 1 Cor 16:22; Gal 1:6-8.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sally Glad to be of service.